# Fabric - Run multiple commands in parallel on a single host

Tags: python, ssh, parallel-processing, fabric

I have a management script that we'll call `mngcntl.sh`.

This script can take up to **5 seconds** to run.

It is located at `x` different places on each server.

I want to execute this script it in parallel for all those locations and get the output of each execution in different StringIO() instances.

**Current approach:**

```
@parallel(pool_size=100)
@task
def manage(script_paths):
    output = {}
    for path in script_paths:
        fh = StringIO()
        script = path + '/' + mngcntl.sh
        run(script, stdout=fh)
        output[path] = fh.getvalue()
```

The problem with my approach is that I have to wait for each script to execute to run the next one.

Currently, if I have `x` scripts on one server, I'll wait around `x * 5` seconds per host to run this task, when ideally I could wait 5 seconds if those commands were run in parallel.

**What I tried so far:**

- Create a task that takes only one script at a time. This takes additional connections on my pool (one SSH connection per script per host) and actually adds even more overhead as I run on more than 100 hosts.
- Execute each script in background using `nohup <script> &` but in this way I can't retrieve the output.
- Execute each script in background using `nohup <script> &> <logfile>` and then later cat each logfile and get the output. This works but I'm having the same problem when running `cat` for each output file (this doesn't execute in parallel)

**Is there a way I can run those scripts in parallel on one host without having to ssh to each host for every script executed ?**

Ideally I'd like to have a pool of StringIO() instances (or a Queue) and having a resource `multirun` that I would run like:

```
multirun(list_of_cmds, stdout=list_of_fh)
```

Comment: **Fabric** does support parallel execution, see [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/parallel.html), although they mention it's not thread-safe for version 1.x

Comment: I know that, and am using it to run on multiple hosts. I need parallel execution on the individual host level.

Comment: Oh in that case can't you simply create a task and use **threading** to run several commands in that single host?

Comment: You just mentioned Fabric was not thread-safe ... Although I just found https://github.com/bancek/fabric-threadsafe so I'll try it out

Comment: I haven't tried that before with fabric but why don't use ProcessPool or something similar on every host? You can process data in parallel, gather results and do what you need to do...

Comment: Are you referring to Unix ProcessPool ? If so, I don't see how this could integrates with Fabric as fabric provides utility functions to run commands like `run`, `execute`, `sudo`.

Comment: You're right. On the other hand, you can always deploy a python script and run it via fabric. It's bit awkward but it might work.

Comment: @Anzel, your comment is not in agreement with the documention. The documentation wording clearly says that the internals of Fabric are not threadsafe; therefore, the parallel execution capabilities are implemented using the multiprocessing module. This means that each task runs in its own process. As the docs point out, most tasks don't interact with each other, so it's safe to run them in separate processes independent of each other.